# using super returns child's value

Tags: java

In the following program:

```
class Feline { 
    public String type = "f "; 
    public Feline() { System.out.print("feline "); } 
} 

public class Cougar extends Feline { 
    public Cougar() { System.out.print("cougar "); } 
    void go() { type = "c "; System.out.print(this.type + super.type); } 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        new Cougar().go(); //1
    } 
}
```

Here,I expect output as, `feline cougar c f` but actual output is, `feline cougar c c`.
Shouldn't `super.type` return value of `type` of super class rather than that of child ?

Also,replacing statement marked as `//1` with

`Feline fe= new Cougar();
System.out.print(fe.type);`

will print `fe.type` as `c`.So,super's `type` isn't lost at all,then why `super.type` doesn't retrieve parent class `type` field value ?

Comment: There aren't separate values, the `Cougar` inherits *one* `type` from `Feline`. And you modify that `type`.

Comment: There's only one `type` variable declared anywhere in the code, why would you think it would hold two values?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I have updated by question.

Comment: @David I have updated by question.

Comment: You didn't call `go` yet. That is what *modifies* the value.

Comment: @Flame: What did you change?  Any given instance has one "type" value.  Because there's only one variable called "type" in the class.  When you call "go()" you set that value to "c ".  So any time after calling "go()" the value will be "c ".

Comment: It seems if variable declarations are same on child and parent,then inside object of child, it replaces value of parent but while referencing child object with parent's type variables aren't overriden.

Comment: @Flame: This child class isn't *overriding* anything.  There's only one "type" variable here.  You never declare another one, overridden or otherwise.  One variable can hold one value.

Comment: thanks @David, I think I got the point.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the way class extension works.

When you extend a class, as you are doing with `Cougar` that extends `Feline`, you will inherit all fields from the super class (you inherit the so called 'state'). However, if you re-define those fields in the child, the only value that will be present will be the lastly-defined in the class tree (i.e., `c` in your case for the `type` field).

If you want to keep the two types, you should define two different fields.

Comment: However, replacing statement marked as `//1` with `Feline fe= new Cougar();
            System.out.print(fe.type);` will print `fe.type` as `c`.So,super's `type` isn't lost at all,then why `super.type` doesn't retrieve parent class `type` field value ?